# facebook, how to redirect the user after login?

Tags: php, facebook

i am trying to redirect the user to a different page after a successful login.

i have this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'11898121834', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
      window.location = "facebook_login.php";
      //alert ("hello");
  });
  </script>
  <fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins" >Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

this wont work. the page refreshes but to the same page.

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert the new page you want to redirect to in the href attribute

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
      window.location.href = "http://example.com/newpage";

  });
```